# URLs sorted by "Frequent" crash the app

Tags: bug, ios-app, sorting

Tapping on links like this one crash the app, sending me to the home screen of my phone:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=frequent

The app doesn’t have a Frequent tab. It still shouldn’t be crashing though.

It’s worth mentioning that nonsense sorts like the following *don’t* crash the app:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=hhjjfdf

Instead the sort is ignored.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone SE
- OS Version: Version 12.1 (Build 16B92)